# Turing reductions by NX ∩ coNX and binary relation problems

Tags: computability, reductions, decision-problem

Let $A$ be a [non-deterministic algorithm](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node88.html) computing a binary relation between an input string and possible output strings. Let NX be a (potentially non-deterministic) complexity class. What is a good definition of a [Turing reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) to $A$, in the context of the decision problems NX<sup>$A$</sup> solvable by an NX Turing reduction to $A$?

- It would be nice if a Turing reduction would ignore any resources (like time, space, random bits, ...) used by algorithm $A$ itself, when it is part of a larger program.
- It would be nice if a Turing reduction would only depend on the computed binary relation, not on the specific algorithm $A$ used to compute the relation.
- It would be nice if the complement of the binary relation would lead to the same Turing reduction as the binary relation itself. So if $B$ is a non-deterministic algorithm computing the complement of the binary relation computed by $A$, then NX<sup>$A$</sup>=NX<sup>$B$</sup>.
  **Edit:** Note however Ricky Demer's comment. The complement is problematic anyway, because arbitrarily long output strings would be required. So better restrict this to the case where the output strings have a fixed length (potentially dependent on the length of the input string), and only refer to the complement relative to this fixed length.
- It would be nice if an NX Turing reduction to $A$ would at least enable us to do everything we could do if we had *subroutines* $A',B'\in\text{FNX}$, where FNX would be the *binary relation* problem class associated to the complexity class NX, $A'$ would compute the same binary relation as $A$, and $B'$ would compute the complement of the binary relation.

This last point raises the following question: If such $A'$ and $B'$ exist, will it lead to NX<sup>$A$</sup>=NX? Or to go back to decision problems (because those are better studied and understood), do we (normally) have NX<sup>$D$</sup>=NX for decision problems $D\in$ NX ∩ coNX?

---

It is common practice to reduce (binary relation and) function problems to decision problems by posing a separate decision question to *an oracle* for each bit of the function value. To enable this sort of reduction, arbitrary decision problems $D\in$ NX ∩ coNX could be composed with the binary relation to get decision problems. Then a Turing reduction must be able to answer those decision problems (for the resource cost of solving $D$ with the implicitly produced output string of $A$ as input). Is this a good definition of the Turing reduction NX<sup>$A$</sup>?
**Edit:** Note that the composition of the complement of $D$ with the complement of the binary relation is different from the complement of the composition. So this part of the question is not affected by the issues related to the complement of a binary relation, because it doesn't try to incorporate the corresponding desirable property.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the Turing reduction" "of a complexity class", but one immediately gets a definition of NX$^A$ from a definition of NX$^F$ for actual functions F, and "the complement of the binary relation" definitely does not need to lead to the same class. ​ (For example, consider [UP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:U#up) relations.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer The point with the complement is very good. It made me realize that the "it would be nice" items would indeed have been too nice (for quite obvious reasons). There are limits to how much I can clarify what I mean by "the Turing reduction" "of a complexity class" (I tried to explain it by analogy with the same notion for decision problem now), because in a certain sense the question exactly asks for "a good definition", i.e. a meaning of those words.

Comment: ... You're using **hugely** non-standard terminology. ​ Usually, Turing reductions are instead the oracle machines, and your description is of the functions with an NX Turing reduction to $A$. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: "of the Turing" ​ -> ​ "of a Turing" ​ ​ ​ ? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​